# Combine columns based on sequential range R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that I want to combine.

```
Jak
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10


Start    Stop    ID    Info
1        3       Ab    Abacus
7        10      Bc    Because
```

I want the final dataframe to be:

```
Jak  ID    Info
1    Ab    Abacus
2    Ab    Abacus
3    Ab    Abacus
4
5
6
7    Bc    Because
8    Bc    Because
9    Bc    Because
10   Bc    Because
```

Where the sequential numbers are matched based on the start and stop columns, and if the sequential number is in that range, add information from the ID and Info columns.

Comment: Is 'Stop' in second dataframe supposed to be 10 instead of 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *base* you can use `merge` after you have created a `seq` from Start to Stop:

```
merge(x, do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, Jak=mapply(seq, y$Start, y$Stop), ID=y$ID,
  Info=y$Info)), all.x=TRUE)
#   Jak   ID    Info
#1    1   Ab  Abacus
#2    2   Ab  Abacus
#3    3   Ab  Abacus
#4    4 <NA>    <NA>
#5    5 <NA>    <NA>
#6    6 <NA>    <NA>
#7    7   Bc Because
#8    8   Bc Because
#9    9   Bc Because
#10  10   Bc Because
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(Jak=1:10)
y <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Start    Stop    ID    Info
1        3       Ab    Abacus
7        10      Bc    Because")
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df2 %>% mutate(Jak = map2(Start, Stop, `:`)) %>% 
unnest(Jak) %>% select(3:5) %>% right_join(df1) %>% 
arrange(Jak) %>% select(3,1,2)
Joining, by = "Jak"
# A tibble: 10 x 3
     Jak ID    Info   
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
 1     1 Ab    Abacus 
 2     2 Ab    Abacus 
 3     3 Ab    Abacus 
 4     4 NA    NA     
 5     5 NA    NA     
 6     6 NA    NA     
 7     7 Bc    Because
 8     8 Bc    Because
 9     9 Bc    Because
10    10 Bc    Because
```

Data used:

```
df1
# A tibble: 10 x 1
     Jak
   <dbl>
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
 5     5
 6     6
 7     7
 8     8
 9     9
10    10
df2
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Start  Stop ID    Info   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
1     1     3 Ab    Abacus 
2     7    10 Bc    Because
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Stop` condition in second dataframe is 10 you can use `fuzzyjoin`

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Jak' = 'Start', 'Jak' = 'Stop'), 
                           match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`))

#   Jak Start Stop   ID    Info
#1    1     1    3   Ab  Abacus
#2    2     1    3   Ab  Abacus
#3    3     1    3   Ab  Abacus
#4    4    NA   NA <NA>    <NA>
#5    5    NA   NA <NA>    <NA>
#6    6    NA   NA <NA>    <NA>
#7    7     7   10   Bc Because
#8    8     7   10   Bc Because
#9    9     7   10   Bc Because
#10  10     7   10   Bc Because
```